# Why does my Perl program appear to freeze on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: perl

I've upgraded to MacOS X Lion. After that, I've updated MacPorts to the newest version (2.0.1) and updated Perl as the following:

```
[Khang-Le-Nguyens-MacBook-Pro:~] khanglenguyen% perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 12 subversion 3) configuration:

  Platform:
osname=darwin, osvers=11.0.0, archname=darwin-multi-2level
uname='darwin khang-le-nguyens-macbook-pro.local 11.0.0 darwin kernel version 11.0.0: sat jun 18 12:56:35 pdt 2011; root:xnu-1699.22.73~1release_x86_64 x86_64 '
config_args='-D inc_version_list=5.12.2/darwin-multi-2level 5.12.2 5.12.1/darwin-multi-2level 5.12.1 5.12.0/darwin-multi-2level 5.12.0 -des -Dprefix=/opt/local -Dscriptdir=/opt/local/bin -Dcppflags=-I/opt/local/include -Dccflags=-pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Dldflags=-L/opt/local/lib -arch x86_64 -Dvendorprefix=/opt/local -Dusemultiplicity=y -D cc=/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -D ld=/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -D man1ext=1pm -D man3ext=3pm -D man1dir=/opt/local/share/man/man1p -D man3dir=/opt/local/share/man/man3p -D siteman1dir=/opt/local/share/man/man1 -D siteman3dir=/opt/local/share/man/man3 -D vendorman1dir=/opt/local/share/man/man1 -D vendorman3dir=/opt/local/share/man/man3 -D pager=/usr/bin/less -sR'
hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
useithreads=undef, usemultiplicity=define
useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
cc='/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2', ccflags ='-pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -I/opt/local/include -no-cpp-precomp -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/opt/local/include',
optimize='-O3',
cppflags='-I/opt/local/include -no-cpp-precomp -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -I/opt/local/include -no-cpp-precomp -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/opt/local/include'
ccversion='', gccversion='4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)', gccosandvers=''
intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
ld='env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3 /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2', ldflags ='-L/opt/local/lib -arch x86_64 -fstack-protector'
libpth=/opt/local/lib /usr/lib
libs=-ldbm -ldl -lm -lutil -lc
perllibs=-ldl -lm -lutil -lc
libc=, so=dylib, useshrplib=false, libperl=libperl.a
gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=bundle, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags='-L/opt/local/lib -arch x86_64 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                    PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_MALLOC_WRAP USE_64_BIT_ALL
                    USE_64_BIT_INT USE_LARGE_FILES USE_PERLIO
                    USE_PERL_ATOF
  Built under darwin
  Compiled at Aug 10 2011 22:28:59
  @INC:
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
```

However, Perl is freezed now and I cannot understand the reasons:

```
[Khang-Le-Nguyens-MacBook-Pro] khanglenguyen% perl matchtopic.pl
```

I've been waiting for a long while but nothing happens.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What is `matchtopic.pl`?

Comment: Why not just use the version of Perl that comes as part of Mac OS X ?

Comment: @duskwuff: matchtopic.pl is just a perl file. I wanna excute it.

Comment: @Paul R: I wanna manage all unix-based packages by MacPorts. Perl works well if the version as Mac OS X is used?

Comment: Without knowing what `matchtopic.pl` is, we really can't debug this problem.

Comment: @duskwuff: For your concern, this is the content of matchtopic.pl

`#!/usr/bin/perl

$inputline = <STDIN>;
print ($inputline);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working as expected; this has nothing to do with the version of Perl you're using. The script that you're running (as noted in a comment) waits for a line of input before printing it. If you don't type anything in, it won't do anything until you do.

Comment: I'm sick, really. Doing complicated project and failing to check a small test. Thank you @duskwuff. I got it.